# Choice field event handler

Tags: 2010, event-receivers, choice-field

I have a drop-down choice field in a custom list

I'd like to add an event handler that fires when a value is selected from the drop down.

I'd originally attached to the itemupdating event but don't want people to have to save the item for the event to fire and I can't see a list item event associated with changes to field values.  Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for cannot be done using event handlers. You need to use selected index changed event of the dropdown control in your form pages.

Comment: Many thanks Nadeem - I was starting to think that was the case.  I'm new to this and was just wondering if you could point me at some relevant references to learn a bit more about the approach you outlined?

Comment: Hi @DanA, you can perhaps use a combination of JQuery and CSOM (Client side object model) to achieve what you want. What you need to do is to add a Content Editor Webpart to your pages like NewFrom.aspx and EditForm.aspx. Write the JQuery and CSOM code in there and make it invisible. You may find these links useful: http://lavssharepointworld.blogspot.in/2013/01/pre-populate-sharepoint-yesno-column-in.html            http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/hidedisplay-controls-newformaspx-69633.aspx

Comment: Thanks again Nadeem - looks like I've got some learning to do!